# adding ngModule in HTML giving Error in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am working on Angular 2 project. Everything is good in startup but when adding ngModule for data binding in HTML then it is giving me an error and page is not loading .

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
at SyntaxError.set [as stack] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1628:63)
at assignAll (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:704:29)
at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError
```

I am adding below my files to review

main.ts

```
  import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';  

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,LoginComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<login-selector></login-selector>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Login.componentr.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-selector',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent  { 
    name = 'Angular'; 

    constructor(){

    }

    login(){
        console.log("Login");
    }

    reset(){
        console.log("reset");   
    }

    refreshCaptcha(){
        console.log("refreshcaptcha");  
    }

    getCaptcha(){
        console.log("getCaptcha");  
    }

    //this.getCaptcha();
    forgetPassword(){
        console.log("forgetPassword");      
    }
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to `0.7.6` or downgrade to `0.7.4` zonejs library https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/595 to see the real error

Comment: Which bundler you use? Maybe `templateUrl` is incorrect path to html file

Comment: oki Thanks Let me try ...

Comment: its a path Error.. Thanks